# When are COLUMN aliases in FROM clauses needed?

Tags: postgresql, alias

[`FROM` provides *`column_alias`*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM), the SQL spec calls these `<derived column list>` clauses. This is what the postgres docs say about them,

> A substitute name for the `FROM` item containing the alias. An alias is used for brevity or to eliminate ambiguity for self-joins (where the same table is scanned multiple times). When an alias is provided, it completely hides the actual name of the table or function; for example given `FROM foo AS f`, the remainder of the `SELECT` must refer to this `FROM` item as `f` not `foo`. If an alias is written, a column alias list can also be written to provide substitute names for one or more columns of the table.

When are these needed? When can I not otherwise just use a COLUMN alias?

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table_name AS t (a,b,c);
```

vs

```
SELECT t.col1 AS a, t.col2 AS b, t.col3 AS c
FROM table_name AS t;
```

This example taken from [the chosen answer by @ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/154354/2639) which doesn't seem too useful.

FROM aliases in the above context provide no real benefit unless you're

- relying on partial aliasing (NOT aliasing the whole table)
- that is dependent on ascending column ordering
- your table has more than three columns (or you could just write it explicitly in the from clause).

It seems like doing that relies on the hazards of regular `t.*` stacked with added obscurity. So when is `FROM` aliasing useful?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### If the columns don't exist (VALUES clause)

PostgreSQL gives them default names, but that's besides the point. You can't alias them in a COLUMN list that doesn't exist.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (VALUES ('row1',1), ('row2',2)) AS t;
```

That would be a great example of the [VALUES LIST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html) syntax which requires you to alias in `FROM` list.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (VALUES ('row1',1), ('row2',2)) AS t(english,rownum);
```

From there you can even use the alias in the select list.

```
SELECT rownum
FROM (VALUES ('row1',1), ('row2',2)) AS t(english,rownum);
```

And, that brings us to a complex example like this one found on page 190 of [PostGIS in Action, Second Edition](https://www.manning.com/books/postgis-in-action-second-edition).

```
SELECT
  oid --**only possible because of FROM ALIASING.**
  , lowrite(lo_open(oid, 131072), img) As num_bytes
FROM (
  VALUES (
    lo_create(0),
    (
      SELECT
        ST_AsGDALRaster(
          ST_Band(rast,1)
          , 'USGSDEM'
          , ARRAY[
            'PRODUCER=' || quote_literal('postgis_in_action')
            , 'INTERNALNAME=' || quote_literal(rast_name)
          ]
        ) As dem
      FROM ch07.bag_o_rasters
      WHERE rast_name = 'Raster 1 band heatmap'
    )
  )
) As v(oid,img); --**FROM ALIASING**
```

If that's hard to swallow there is one other awkward construct there and that's a SELECT as a COLUMN.

```
SELECT ( SELECT 1 ), ( SELECT 2 ); -- one row "1,2"

SELECT lo_create(0), ( SELECT 2 ); -- one row "oid,2"
```

`lo_create` returns an oid. That's beyond the scope of this answer though.

For another real world example, see [this question I just answered](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155545/2639).

### In a SELF JOIN

This may be worth mentioning since it is in the docs,

```
SELECT * FROM temp;
 foo |  bar   
-----+--------
   1 | evan
   2 | dba.se
(2 rows)
```

And you self-join you'll get two `bar` columns.

```
SELECT * FROM temp JOIN temp AS t2 USING (foo);
 foo |  bar   |  bar   
-----+--------+--------
   1 | evan   | evan
   2 | dba.se | dba.se
(2 rows)
```

But, with FROM aliasing you can label them separately,

```
SELECT * FROM temp JOIN temp AS t2(foo,bar2) USING (foo);
 foo |  bar   |  bar2  
-----+--------+--------
   1 | evan   | evan
   2 | dba.se | dba.se
(2 rows)
```

However, that's **not really better than the COLUMN-aliasing method,**

```
SELECT foo, temp.bar, t2.bar AS bar2
FROM temp JOIN temp AS t2
  USING (foo);
```

The only difference is that uniquely in the FROM-aliasing method you refer to all instance of `t2.bar` as `bar2`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ for real terror, `SELECT "?column?" AS f FROM (SELECT 1) AS t`

Comment: Interesting; so it seems that column aliases in from clauses are never actually *needed* but may (arguably) be more expressive in some cases.

Comment: `UNNEST`ing an array is another example.

Comment: @Wildcard that's [not safe even if true](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html) *The column names are not specified by the SQL standard and different database systems do it differently,* We're just kind of poking fun at a cool PG-trick.

Comment: Ahh, but I'm talking about column aliases for a *table name*, not for a subselect or a WITH clause.  A values call is actually a subselect, not a table.  See the two formats for *from_item* which I list in [my question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154320/104401), quoting from the docs.  Your comment above applies to the second form (subselects) but not to the first.  So my earlier comment could be rephrased: It seems that *table_name*s specified in a FROM clause never **need** to have *column_alias*es, as the same effect could always be achieved by using *output_name*s.  That suit you?  :)

Comment: Yep! That's totally fair, and should probably never use them. I actually posted this originally on your question but I wasn't sure if I was adding to it, or distracting from it so I broke it off into its own thing.