# What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, join

I'm just getting started with Postgres. Reading [this document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-controls.html) I came across this query:

```
SELECT title, ts_rank_cd(textsearch, query) AS rank
FROM apod, to_tsquery('neutrino|(dark & matter)') query
WHERE query @@ textsearch
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I can understand everything in this query, **except** for this: `FROM apod, ...`.

What does this `,` mean? I'm used to joins but not to multiple `FROM` statements separated by a comma.

I searched the net for no avail. After looking at it and thinking, it seems to me that it's declaring a variable called query so it can use it multiple times. But if this is true, what does it have to do with `FROM`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**It creates an implicit `CROSS JOIN`. It's the SQL-89 syntax.**

*Here I use `values(1)` and `values(2)` to create pseduo-tables (value tables) merely for examples. The thing after them `t(x)`, and `g(y)` are called [FROM-Aliases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155616/2639) the character inside the parenthesis is the alias for the column (`x` and `y` respectively). You could just as easily create a table to test this.*

```
SELECT *
FROM (values(1)) AS t(x), (values(2)) AS g(y)
```

Here is how you'd write it now.

```
SELECT *
FROM (values(1)) AS t(x)
CROSS JOIN (values(2)) AS g(y);
```

From there you can make this an implicit `INNER JOIN` by adding a conditional.

```
SELECT *
FROM (values(1)) AS t(x)
CROSS JOIN (values(1)) AS g(z)
WHERE x = z;
```

Or the explicit and newer `INNER JOIN` syntax,

```
SELECT *
FROM (values(1)) AS t(x)
INNER JOIN (values(1)) AS g(z)
  ON ( x = z );
```

So in your example..

```
FROM apod, to_tsquery('neutrino|(dark & matter)') query
```

This is essentially the same as the newer syntax,

```
FROM apod
CROSS JOIN to_tsquery('neutrino|(dark & matter)') AS query
```

which is actually the same, in this case, because `to_tsquery()` returns a row and not a set as,

```
SELECT title, ts_rank_cd(
  textsearch,
  to_tsquery('neutrino|(dark & matter)')
) AS rank
FROM apod
WHERE to_tsquery('neutrino|(dark & matter)') @@ textsearch
ORDER BY rank DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

However, the above could potentially cause `to_tsquery('neutrino|(dark & matter)')` to occur twice, but in this case it doesn't -- `to_tsquery` is marked as [STABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) (verified with `\dfS+ to_tsquery`).

> `STABLE` indicates that the function cannot modify the database, and that within a single table scan it will consistently return the same result for the same argument values, but that its result could change across SQL statements. This is the appropriate selection for functions whose results depend on database lookups, parameter variables (such as the current time zone), etc. (It is inappropriate for AFTER triggers that wish to query rows modified by the current command.) Also note that the current_timestamp family of functions qualify as stable, since their values do not change within a transaction.

For a more complete comparison of the differences between SQL-89, and SQL-92, [see also my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/195447/2639)

Comment: Never heard the term "FROM alias" for a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES). `to_tsquery()` returns a *value* not a *row*. And just because a function is defined `STABLE`, that does not mean the query planner *will* avoid repeated evaluation. It *can*.

Answer (score 14):

The manual has detailed explanation for **the comma in the `FROM` list** in the chapter [Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN):

> The `FROM` Clause derives a table from one or more other tables given in
> a comma-separated table reference list.
>
> `FROM table_reference [, table_reference [, ...]]`
>
> A table reference can be a table name (possibly schema-qualified), or
> a derived table such as a subquery, a `JOIN` construct, or complex
> combinations of these. If more than one table reference is listed in
> the `FROM` clause, the tables are cross-joined (that is, the Cartesian
> product of their rows is formed; see below).

The fact that comma-separated table references have been defined in an earlier version of the SQL standard than explicit `JOIN` syntax does ***not*** make the comma wrong or outdated. Use explicit join syntax, where it's technically necessary (see below) or where it makes the query text clearer.

The manual again:

> `FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2` is equivalent to `FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON TRUE`
> (see below). It is also equivalent to `FROM T1, T2`.

There are corner cases where both are not completely equivalent. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.4.2.1.1)

> **Note**
> This latter equivalence does not hold exactly when more than two
> tables appear, because `JOIN` binds more tightly than comma. For example
> `FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2 INNER JOIN T3 ON condition` is not the same as
> `FROM T1, T2 INNER JOIN T3 ON condition` because the `condition` can
> reference `T1` in the first case but not the second.

This related question demonstrates the relevance of the difference:

- [“invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table” in Postgres query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34598292/939860)

Basically, your observation is exactly right:

> it seems to me that it's declaring a variable called query so it can use it multiple times.

Any function can be used as "table function" in the `FROM` list.
And function parameters can reference columns from all tables to the left of the function, because the notation:

```
FROM apod, to_tsquery('neutrino|(dark & matter)') query
```

... is really equivalent to:

```
FROM apod CROSS JOIN LATERAL to_tsquery('neutrino|(dark & matter)') AS query
```

[The manual on LATERAL queries:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

> Table functions appearing in `FROM` can also be preceded by the key word
> **`LATERAL`, but for functions the key word is optional**; the function's
> arguments can contain references to columns provided by preceding FROM
> items in any case.

**Bold** emphasis mine.

The **keyword `AS`** is completely optional noise before *table aliases* (as opposed to *column aliases*, where it's recommended not to omit `AS` to avoid possible ambiguities). See:

- [Date column arithmetic in PostgreSQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543614/939860)