# Why does this implicit join get planned differently than an explicit join?

Tags: postgresql, join, execution-plan, performance, postgresql-9.5, postgresql-performance

[In this answer I explain SQL-89s implicit syntax.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/167202/2639)
But I noticed different query plans while playing around:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT *
  FROM (values(1)) AS t(x), (values(2)) AS g(y);

                                     QUERY PLAN                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.052 ms
 Execution time: 0.020 ms
(3 rows)
```

Versus this:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT *
  FROM (values(1)) AS t(x)                      
  CROSS JOIN (values(2)) AS g(y);
                                           QUERY PLAN                                           
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Subquery Scan on g  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.075 ms
 Execution time: 0.027 ms
(4 rows)
```

**Why would one of them show `Subquery Scan`?

Isn't the implicit syntax just rewritten to be the same as the explicit syntax?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Isn't the implicit syntax just rewritten to be the same as the explicit syntax?

Not necessarily. You are building on slightly incorrect assumptions. Like I explained under the referenced question:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)

Comma-separated items in the `FROM` list are almost, but **not quite *identical* to explicit `CROSS JOIN` notation**. Explicit joins bind stronger. The query planner *has* to handle both cases differently in certain cases.

Obviously, the planner is smart enough to be able to treat `VALUES` expression with a single row expression with a simplified plan. We see a more complex plan for more than one row in the `VALUES` expression:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT *
FROM  (VALUES (1), (2)) t(x)
    , (VALUES (2), (3)) g(y);
```

> ```
>  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.11 rows=4 width=8) (actual time=0.059..0.064 rows=4 loops=1)
>    ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=2 loops=1)
>    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..0.04 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.025..0.026 rows=2 loops=2)
>          ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*_1"  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=2 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=2 loops=1)
> ```

Simplifying the query plan is easier for a `VALUES` expression separated by comma(s). When bound by explicit join(s), Postgres needs to consider join conditions *before* combining with other comma-separated `FROM` items. I expect the "subqery scan" we see for this case is a (completely harmless) side effect of the more complex code path for this case.