# How do I do a JOIN in ANSI SQL 89 syntax?

Tags: join, sql-standard

In Oracle, I use

```
SELECT * FROM table1...JOIN...
```

where the dots represent either the type of join or the condition on which to be joined.

Is this ANSI 89 syntax? If not, then how would I perform a join if I were using ANSI 89?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to use SQL-89 syntax. SQL-89 is just an implicit `CROSS JOIN` ([Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)).

```
SELECT *            -- NEVER
FROM foo, bar;      -- NEVER EVER DO THIS
```

Is the same as the more modern

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN bar;
```

Adding the `WHERE clause` makes it the equivalent of an `INNER JOIN ... ON`

```
SELECT *                         -- DO NOT
FROM foo,bar                     -- DO THIS
WHERE foo.foo_id = bar.foo_id;   -- EVER
```

You want to use SQL-92 Syntax.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar
  ON foo.foo_id = bar.foo_id;
```

Or even better (if the join column is the same and it's an equijoin `=`)

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar
  USING (foo_id);
```

- Note some people don't use `INNER`. That's fine. It's still SQL-92.

See also

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/167201/2639)

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126998/discussion-on-answer-by-i-support-the-boycott-how-do-i-do-a-join-in-ansi-sql-89).