# Query between tables to delete similar records from another table

Tags: postgresql, delete, substring

I am writing an SQL query on two tables `products01` and `products02` in a PostgreSQL database.

For the entire set of records in `products02` take the substring (first 10 characters of `volumeId` and use those substrings to find all the corresponding records in `products01`. There can be more than one hit in `products01`, for instance finding older legacy record of the same item, just a different edition. The eleventh character of `volumeId` makes it unique.

For instance, in `products01` I can have `volumeId`'s like:

```
record45671
record45672
record45673
```

And in `products02` I would be using `substring(volumeId for 10)` or `'record456'` to find those similar records in `products01`.

Also I'd like to display the results so I can verify my query is accurate.

Here is my initial attempt:

```
    SELECT substring(volumeId, for 10) FROM temporary.products01 t01
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT volumeId FROM temporary.products02 t02
        WHERE t01.volumeId LIKE t02.volumeId);
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to the site. Could you add your table definitions, sample data and expected output to the question. Please [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/223785/edit) your question and don't add additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all rows from table `products01` where the 10 leading characters of `volumeId` match any `products02.volumeId`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM   products01 t1
JOIN   products02 t2 ON left(t1.volumeId, 10) = t2.volumeId;
```

To delete:

```
DELETE FROM products01 t1
USING  products02 t2
WHERE  left(t1.volumeId, 10) = t2.volumeId;
```

You can use this equivalent syntax to get both commands more in line:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM products01 t1, -- see below
-- DELETE FROM products01 t1 USING  
products02 t2
WHERE  left(t1.volumeId, 10) = t2.volumeId;
```

Only add `DISTINCT` if `t2.volumeId` is not fully deterministic (`t1.volumeId` can match multiple `t2.volumeId`).

Now you can either select the whole statement to *select* or starting with `DELETE` to *delete*. See:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)
- [The manual on `DELETE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-delete.html)

Comment: Question on this syntax in the JOIN example and in the SELECT DISTINCT example: products02 t2 ON left(t1.volumeId, 10) = t2.volumeId; -- should the "=" be a like since we are using the substring (left func) of t1.

Comment: @user9491577: If `t2.volumeId` consists of 10 characters - the leading 10 characters in `t1.volumeId` - then it's `=`. If not, you need to clarify your question, like has been suggested repeatedly.