# What's the benefit of CROSS JOIN vs INNER JOIN in recursive CTE queries?

Tags: postgresql, join, cte

In [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), the join of non-recursive part to recursive is done via `CROSS JOIN`. Is there some benefit to using it instead of `INNER JOIN`? Is it just a subjective choice?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE folders (id INT, parent INT) ON COMMIT DROP;
INSERT INTO folders
    (id, parent)
    VALUES
    (1, null),
    (2, 1),
    (3, 2);
```

using `CROSS JOIN`

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree (id, parent) AS (
    SELECT id, parent
    FROM folders
    WHERE id = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.id, p.parent
    FROM folders p, tree
    WHERE tree.parent = p.id
)
```

using `INNER JOIN`

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree (id, parent) AS (
    SELECT id, parent
    FROM folders
    WHERE id = 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p.id, p.parent
    FROM folders p
        INNER JOIN tree
        ON tree.parent = p.id
)
```

Comment: the first one you mentioned is an old way of writing an INNER join. I believe all major DBMS vendors translate it to the same execution plan

Comment: TRY the EXPLAIN and see if there is a difference

Comment: @Bijujose no difference.. I thought there might be some use case of using (what seemed to be) CROSS JOIN for some type of CTEs, but I guess not. You can put your comment into an answer and I'll accept, if you want.

Comment: I don't have a Postgres environment to show the EXPLAIN output and show that there is no difference and also not well versed with Postgres. Thanks for your nice gesture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independent of the CTE context, comma-separated items in the `FROM` list are *equivalent* to the same with `CROSS JOIN` replacing the commas. And `[INNER] JOIN` is *exactly* the same as `CROSS JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN)

> `FROM T1 CROSS JOIN T2` is equivalent to `FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON TRUE` (see below). It is also equivalent to `FROM T1, T2`.

But there is a subtle difference between comma and explicit `JOIN` syntax. Comma separates more strictly. See:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)

Answer (score 1):

As [@Bijujose](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/10267/biju-jose) suggested, the seeming `CROSS JOIN` actually acts as an `INNER JOIN` (taking into account the `tree.parent = p.id` join condition), and thus there's no semantical difference.

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` output for each:

```
Limit  (cost=857.87..858.07 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=0.016..0.109 rows=3 loops=1)
  CTE tree
    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..857.87 rows=12441 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.104 rows=3 loops=1)
          ->  Seq Scan on folders  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
                Filter: (id = 3)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 2
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.58..57.08 rows=1243 width=8) (actual time=0.025..0.026 rows=1 loops=3)
                Hash Cond: (p.id = tree_1.parent)
                ->  Seq Scan on folders p  (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=2260 width=8) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=3 loops=2)
                ->  Hash  (cost=2.20..2.20 rows=110 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=3)
                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                      ->  WorkTable Scan on tree tree_1  (cost=0.00..2.20 rows=110 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=3)
  ->  CTE Scan on tree  (cost=0.00..248.82 rows=12441 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.107 rows=3 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.168 ms
Execution time: 0.177 ms

Limit  (cost=857.87..858.07 rows=10 width=8) (actual time=0.017..0.081 rows=3 loops=1)
  CTE tree
    ->  Recursive Union  (cost=0.00..857.87 rows=12441 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.074 rows=3 loops=1)
          ->  Seq Scan on folders  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=11 width=8) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
                Filter: (id = 3)
                Rows Removed by Filter: 2
          ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.58..57.08 rows=1243 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=3)
                Hash Cond: (p.id = tree_1.parent)
                ->  Seq Scan on folders p  (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=2260 width=8) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=3 loops=2)
                ->  Hash  (cost=2.20..2.20 rows=110 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=3)
                      Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 8kB
                      ->  WorkTable Scan on tree tree_1  (cost=0.00..2.20 rows=110 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=3)
  ->  CTE Scan on tree  (cost=0.00..248.82 rows=12441 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.078 rows=3 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.240 ms
Execution time: 0.130 ms
```

Comment: Not that I expect difference but you should try this with a bigger table than 3 rows only and with indexes on the columns involved.