# WITH ... AS statement not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, cte, except

I get this error:

[image: WITH...AS syntax error]

It arises when I try to execute the following query:

```
with expensive_service as (
    select s1.*
    from service s1, service s2
    where s1.price > s2.price
)
select * 
from service except expensive_service;
```

I was trying to implement [`WITH ... AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) (link to PostgreSQL docs).

This query gives me the desired output I'm looking for:

```
select * 
from service except ( 
    select s1.*
    from service s1, service s2
    where s1.price > s2.price
)
```

Any aid directing me where the error lies would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We kindly ask to present text as *text*, not screenshots. Screenshots are blackboxes that deny copy/paste and cannot be searched for. Also please remember to disclose your version of Postgres. Always helpful, sometimes essential. And please explain what your query should do, in plain English. I have reason to believe you want a different query ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Roger. Will keep those tips in mind for next time. The postgres verson I'm using is psql 12.2, server 11.5, AWS RDS. My query was looking to find the least expensive product via its price.

Comment: Seems to match what I deduced: *Get all rows with the minimum price.* Compare performance with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` ... BTW, table definition (`CRATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints) is always instrumental, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CTE (common table expression) is like a view and you need to treat it like any other view (or table). You need a complete SELECT statement as the second part of the EXCEPT:

```
with expensive_service as (
    select s1.*
    from service s1, service s2
    where s1.price > s2.price
)
select * 
from service 
except 
select *
from expensive_service;
```

---

Note that parentheses around the individual parts of a UNION, EXCEPT or INTERSECT are not needed (unless you need an ORDER BY for **only** that query, e.g. because you are using a LIMIT clause).

So your original query could (should in my opinion) also be written as

```
select * 
from service 
except  
select s1.*
from service s1, service s2
where s1.price > s2.price
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That answered my question and then some.

Answer (score 2):

> This query gives me the desired output I'm looking for:

Use this instead!

```
SELECT *
FROM   service
WHERE  price = (SELECT min(price) FROM service)
-- OR  price IS NULL  -- add if price can be NULL
```

Be sure to have an index on `(price)` if your table is big.

The currently accepted answer has good technical information, but the actual query should never be used. Also, you would typically want `EXCEPT ALL` instead of `EXCEPT`. See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

But don't.

#### Why?

The implicit `CROSS JOIN` in the second `SELECT` scales with **O(N²)**. What does it do?

```
...
SELECT s1.*
FROM   service s1, service s2
WHERE  s1.price > s2.price
```

This returns one copy of every row for every other row in the table with a smaller `price` (or where `price IS NULL`). What for? To exclude those in the next step. Meaning, only rows with the smallest price (or `price IS NULL`) are *not* excluded.
In other words:

***Get all rows with the minimum `price` (or `price IS NULL`).***

Related:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)