# Does MariaDB or MySQL implement the VALUES (expression) table value constructor?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, sql-standard, mariadb-10.3

I am just wondering if MariaDB or MySQL implements the `<table value constructor>` in the SQL Spec. In [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [PostgreSQL this is done with standardized `VALUES (expression)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html)?

```
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x);
 x 
---
 1
(1 row)
```

(syntax from [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql)).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## MariaDB 10.3+

Yes, speaking of [MariaDB 10.3.3 and later it seems to support table value constructors.](https://modern-sql.com/blog/2018-08/whats-new-in-mariadb-10.3)

```
SELECT 1, t.7
FROM (VALUES (7),(42)) AS t;
 1 |  7
--------
 1 |  7
 1 |  42
```

You'll notice that there is no support for [column_alias](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/155615/2639) in the `FROM` clause, instead requiring you to use the table_alias and the name of the **first row's value for that column**. But column_alias are allowed in a CTE's `WITH` clause,

```
WITH t(a) AS ( VALUES (1),(2) )
SELECT t.a, t.a AS b
FROM t;
 a |  b
--------
 1 |  1
 2 |  2
```

Additionally you may able to skirt this by giving the first row a definitive alias.

```
SELECT 1 AS x ,2 AS y
UNION VALUES (3,4),(5,6);
 x | y
-------
 1 | 2
 3 | 4
 5 | 6
```

also see examples in https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-12172

---

*PostgreSQL permits [column aliases in FROM clauses](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154320/2639), as show above with `t(x)`, this syntax is also not supported in MariaDB*

## MariaDB <10.3; MySQL 5.x & 8.x (Workaround)

Prior to MariaDB 10.3, and all versions of MySQL do not support the `VALUES` expression.

```
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (1) ) AS t(x);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (1) ) AS t(x)' at line 1
```

However, it does support sub-selects with literals.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT (1) AS x) AS t;
-- more simply
-- SELECT * FROM (SELECT 1 AS x) AS t;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

PostgreSQL also supports this syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 1 AS x ) AS t;
 x 
---
 1
(1 row)
```

However, things get a lot more verbose with this syntax if you're doing multiple rows. *Below from MariaDB, also works in PostgreSQL*

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 2 ) AS t;
+---+
| x |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
+---+
```

Whereas with `VALUES`, it's simply `VALUES (1),(2)`

Comment: MySQL 8 seems to want `VALUES ROW(), ROW(), ROW()` instead of the more compact syntax using only parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above, the syntax between MySQL 8 and MariaDB doesn't appear to be the same (MySQL requires the `ROW` keyword around the individual row values, MariaDB wants parentheses)

However you can use `json_table` to do the same thing, and that works the same for both.

```sql
SELECT * FROM json_table(
  "[1,2,3,4]", 
  '$[*]' COLUMNS(c1 INT PATH '$' ERROR ON ERROR)
) as t;
```

It's a great deal more concise than `UNION ALL` for each row (though it's not as well supported on older versions)